# Movie about a man with 2 alternate lives (reality and in dreams)

Tags: story-identification, movie, parallel-universe

I barely remember a movie about a man (or maybe woman) who had 2 lives: when he goes to sleep he wakes up in his dream, and when he falls asleep in his dream he wakes up in his real life.
But he couldn't tell which life is his dream and which one is reality. As I recall, he was a scientist and he started taking notes and sending letters and messages to himself.

I know it is not much but does it sound familiar to anyone?

Edit: I remember now that I saw this on tv around 10 years ago. Perhaps the movie was from Poland or Checkslovakia or other central/eastern european country.

Edit2: A friend of mine told me that he also saw this movie. As he remembers it was a sequel of [Accumulator 1](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109071/) and it was called "akumulátor dvá", but can't find it on the internet.

Comment: I guess there are a bunch of stories like that. Could it be the same story as in [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115063/schrodingers-butterfly-style-story-about-an-office-worker-and-gunpowder)? That one was identified as ["Dreamer's Worlds"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?82075) by [Edmond Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmond_Hamilton), which you can read at [Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Weird_Tales/Volume_36/Issue_2/Dreamer%27s_Worlds).

Comment: If it really is the same story (not very likely) then, unless you're old enough to remember stories from the [November 1941 *Weird Tales*](http://www.philsp.com/data/images/w/weird_tales_194111.jpg), you must have read it the 1974 Edmond Hamilton collection [*What's It Like Out There? and Other Stories*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?54286).

Comment: There was a 2012  tv show; Awake. The premise was about this cop, who after waking up from an accident induced coma, found himself in one reality,where his wife had died in the accident, would go to sleep and be awake in another where his son had died. He couldn't tell which was the real one. He used information gained from one reality to help himself in the other

Comment: @user14111 I don't remember the medieval part, so I guess it is not that story. But it sounds interesting, thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: Doctor Who's [_Amy's Choice_](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1591788) would also fit. Or how about [_Family Man_](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0218967/) with Nicolas Cage? In other words, we need more specificity.

Comment: @MrLister I wish I remember more specifics.

Comment: It was an older black and white movie, right? We're just sitting around trying to remember what it was called too. That's how I cam across this conversation. Lol.

Comment: There was a made for TV movie with this theme. Sometime in the late 70's or in the 80's. If I think if over for a couple of years, it might come back to me. The main character might have been Christopher George, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @michael As I recall it was an old movie but don't know if it was black and white.

Comment: Excerpt from czech movie database: Name "Accumulator 1" was intended to confuse viewers that sequel(s) exists.

Comment: user98495's deleted answer says that the film involved Jack Lemmon and Chris Lemmon playing the two characters, but I don't see a matching film where they both starred. http://www.imdb.com/search/title?roles=nm0000493,nm0501422&title_type=feature,tv_episode,video,tv_movie,tv_special,mini_series,documentary,game,short