# Tv movie about man living parallel life in dreams

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, dreams

This was something I saw on TV a long time ago, I'm pretty sure it would have been in the 1970s. I came in partway through so I don't know the whole plot, and I don't know if it was a movie or an episode of a TV series. The protagonist had recurring dreams in which he seemed to be leading a separate life, completely different to his real life. Strange things started happening in real life, stuff leaking out of his dream life, increasingly supernatural events happening. I think I remember a house vanishing into thin air at one point. In the end it turned out

> nothing supernatural was going on - he'd just been mistaken all along about which world was reality and which was the dream.

[This unanswered question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125586/story-or-movie-about-a-man-with-2-alternate-lives-reality-and-in-dreams) *might* be the same movie, it's hard to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The Deadly Dream"(1971 Made for TV movie)?

I can't find much online about this, but here is the plot summary from IMDb.

"A scientist keeps having dreams that he is marked for murder by a mysterious tribunal for something that he's not aware that he's done, and that his wife and his friends are part of the conspiracy. Soon he's not sure which is the dream and which is reality."

Here is the IMDb page, if you read the reviews, they describe the plot in more detail.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066972/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1

Comment: Yes, that looks very much like the one I remember. Thanks!